# Serial port class wrapper for serial port object VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

I've been reviewing some code that I maintain recently, and I came across this wrapper object for the serial port class. I'm trying to understand the advantage of this seemingly redundant object:

```
Public Class SerialPort_Class
Private WithEvents Serial_Port As IO.Ports.SerialPort

Private SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag As Boolean = True
Private ReadOnly Common_Methods As New Common_Class

Private _BaudRate As Integer = 115200
Private _DataBits As Integer = 8
Private _DiscardNull As Boolean = False
Private _DtrEnable As Boolean = False
Private _Encoding As Text.Encoding = Text.Encoding.ASCII
Private _Handshake As IO.Ports.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
Private _NewLine As String = vbLf 'Default
Private _Parity As IO.Ports.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
Private _ParityReplace As Byte = Byte.MinValue 'If the value is set to the null character, parity replacement is disabled
Private _PortName As String = "None" 'Default of Nothing, Prevent Occupying Com Port Until Set
Private _ReadBufferSize As Integer = 4096
Private _ReadTimeout As Integer = 250
Private _ReceivedBytesThreshold As Integer = 1
Private _RtsEnable As Boolean = False
Private _StopBits As IO.Ports.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
Private _WriteBufferSize As Integer = 2048
Private _WriteTimeout As Integer = 250

Private Shared ReadOnly Search_Com_Lock_Object As New Object

Public Property BaudRate As Integer
    Get
        Return _BaudRate
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value.Equals(_BaudRate) Then Return
        _BaudRate = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property DataBits As Integer
    Get
        Return _DataBits
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value.Equals(_DataBits) Then Return
        _DataBits = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property DiscardNull As Boolean
    Get
        Return _DiscardNull
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        If value.Equals(_DiscardNull) Then Return
        _DiscardNull = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property DtrEnable As Boolean
    Get
        Return _DtrEnable
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        If value.Equals(_DtrEnable) Then Return
        _DtrEnable = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Encoding As Text.Encoding
    Get
        Return _Encoding
    End Get
    Set(value As Text.Encoding)
        If value.Equals(_Encoding) Then Return
        _Encoding = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Handshake As IO.Ports.Handshake
    Get
        Return _Handshake
    End Get
    Set(value As IO.Ports.Handshake)
        If value.Equals(_Handshake) Then Return
        _Handshake = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property NewLine As String
    Get
        Return _NewLine
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If value.Equals(_NewLine) Then Return
        _NewLine = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Parity As IO.Ports.Parity
    Get
        Return _Parity
    End Get
    Set(value As IO.Ports.Parity)
        If value.Equals(_Parity) Then Return
        _Parity = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ParityReplace As Byte
    Get
        Return _ParityReplace
    End Get
    Set(value As Byte)
        If value.Equals(_ParityReplace) Then Return
        _ParityReplace = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property PortName As String
    Get
        Return _PortName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If value.Equals(_PortName) Then Return
        _PortName = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ReadBufferSize As Integer
    Get
        Return _ReadBufferSize
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value.Equals(_ReadBufferSize) Then Return
        _ReadBufferSize = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ReadTimeout As Integer
    Get
        Return _ReadTimeout
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value.Equals(_ReadTimeout) Then Return
        _ReadTimeout = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ReceivedBytesThreshold As Integer
    Get
        Return _ReceivedBytesThreshold
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value.Equals(_ReceivedBytesThreshold) Then Return
        _ReceivedBytesThreshold = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property RtsEnable As Boolean
    Get
        Return _RtsEnable
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        If value.Equals(_RtsEnable) Then Return
        _RtsEnable = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property StopBits As IO.Ports.StopBits
    Get
        Return _StopBits
    End Get
    Set(value As IO.Ports.StopBits)
        If value.Equals(_StopBits) Then Return
        _StopBits = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property WriteBufferSize As Integer
    Get
        Return _WriteBufferSize
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value.Equals(_WriteBufferSize) Then Return
        _WriteBufferSize = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
Public Property WriteTimeout As Integer
    Get
        Return _WriteTimeout
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value.Equals(_WriteTimeout) Then Return
        _WriteTimeout = value
        SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there more code in this class? it looks like other objects are instantiated, but not used:

```
Private ReadOnly Common_Methods As New Common_Class
```

and

```
Private Shared ReadOnly Search_Com_Lock_Object As New Object
```

To answer your question, this code can be simplified. Is the truth bit that has been added to each statement for determining if the port is open?

```
SerialPort_ReOpen_Flag = True
```

if so it would be better to use the built-in SerialPort.IsOpen Property to check when the port is open.
After removing that flag you can remove the getter and setter methods and just use the Auto-implemented syntax for properties like _BaudRate. You can review this type of setup in the [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Thank you for your input. Common_Methods and Search_Com_Lock_Object are used in functions later on within the class. I didn't show the entire class because it is 1,220 lines of code and it contains some proprietary information.

Comment: holy moly, I've worked with a range of hardware devices and I've never seen a VB.NET serial port wrapper need more than 300 lines of code.